# How to not lose credentials, form data, and active tabs while still use DU Speed Booster app?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, cache

I have installed [DU Speed Booster app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay) and use it regularly on my Android Device which I believe is running version 4.4.2 Kit Kat .

I always lose information stored on forms that I would like to maintain, mainly  Login Ids , Passwords, opened tabs I am working with, and more.

Could someone guide me here with this troubling issue?

Comment: Lisa, could you please clear these questions? 1. How do you use DU Speed Booster App,  and what is its regards to your question. 2. What browser do you use, Of which you lose the form data and login credentials. 3. What are you talking about .memo and youtube **Please try to be as much as informative** you can be. One cannot make house without clay. And do not worry we will get the solution definately. Lastly, welcome to stackexchange :)

Comment: Lisa, You mean Login data is lost when you use the DU Speed Booster app? Add the browser you are using to the ignore list in that app.(telling DU speed booster not to clear login data).

Comment: Lucky,   Thank you very much... Yes that is exactly the help I was hoping for..  again Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lucky says in the comment above:

Add the browser you are using to the ignore list within DU Speed Booster, the app cache will be retained when clearing the cache.

Comment: Don't take it otherwise, but I think this should've been a Wiki Answer since the content is already covered by [Lucky in this comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112604/how-to-not-lose-credentials-form-data-and-active-tabs-while-still-use-du-speed#comment139215_112604), or at least a mention of his name and comment should be done.

Comment: @Firelord good shout, I was hoping that Lucky would post an answer anyway, so I could delete mine, but Wiki Answer does the job too.